# How to catch an exception in a configuration bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I catch an exception thrown by the doSomeThing() method call, and throwing it afterwards?

```
@Configuration
Class conf{

@Bean
public Function<A, B> method() {
    return valueA -> {
    B valueB = doSomeThing(valueA);
    return valueB;
  };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to catch and throw an `Exception` that is thrown in a Functional interface. But you can handle if it is a checked exception like:

```
@Configuration
class conf {

    @Bean
    public Function<A, B> method() {
        return valueA -> {
            B valueB = doSomeThing(valueA);
            return valueB;
        };
    }
    
    B doSomeThing(A valueA) {
        try {
            return new B();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // you can convert checked exception into an unchecked exception here
            throw new RuntimeException()
        }
    }
}
```